# Firebase rule to only allow users to write with their device token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Assuming users don't create an account and only use device token, one can have this structure:

```
users/${device_token}/posts
```

Now, how can you protect that each user can only access their own posts?

I have used this in the past: `.write: "$uid === auth.uid"` when I had each user create an account and log in. How can I get a similar result when users don't create an account and just use device token?

Comment: Are you mentioning firebase cloud messaging(FCM) device token here? Assuming it is token generated by FCM, Firebase doesn't have that device token in their auth variable. Either you have to store it somewhere in the db to refer it in the security rule.

Answer (score 0):

Only the currently authenticated Firebase Authentication user is available in Firebase Database security rules. Since the FCM token is not part of a user object, the FCM device token is not available in the Firebase Database security rules.

So you will need to use Firebase Authentication to ensure that there is a current user. Luckily you can use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) to ensure there is a current user without the user having to explicitly sign in. This makes the `auth.uid` in your security rules work again.

The next step is to associate the user profile with the FCM device token. I can quickly think of two ways to do that:

1. Store the token in the user's profile as an additional claim.
2. Store the token in the database associated with the UID.

To **store the token in the user's profile**, you'll need to use the Firebase Admin SDK. This means this that you need to run this code on a trusted environment, such as a server you control or Cloud Functions. Once you have this, [setting a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) is as easy as:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {deviceToken: "....."});
```

And you'd use it in your security rules as:

```
".write": "auth.token.deviceToken === '...'",
```

Read the documentation for more info as there are some limits to what you can set.

A more flexible, but more cumbersome, approach is to **store the token in the database**. To do this you add a new top-level node to the database, where you store the token for each user:

```
tokens
  $uid: "..."
```

You'll want to secure this part of the database so that [users can only write their own token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable).

After that you can access this node in the other rule to check their token. For example:

```
".write": "root.child('tokens').child(auth.uid).val() === $token".
```